Is there anything like Haskell "guarded equations" in modern C++?
I would like to know if there are equivalent to Haskell guarded equations in Modern C++ (C++20, C++23). Here is an example from Richard Bird's Haskell book where guided equations are used:
combine2 :: (Int, Int) -> String
combine2 (t, u)
   | t == 0            = units!!u
   | t == 1            = teens!!u
   | 2 <= t && u == 0  = tens!!(t-2)
   | 2 <= t && u /= 0  = tens!!(t-2) ++ "-" ++ units!!u

Is there a way of defining combine2 using guarded equations (or equivalent to them) in C++20? (I find use of guarded equations very beautiful!)

I don't think there's an elegant equivalent. You'll probably need to use several if/elses.

pattern matching?, but that's just a proposal, not part of any standard yet.
